# Draw an asterisk analog clock for hour N

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

### Challenge:

Create a function or program that will take an input N (a number from 0 - 24) which represents the HOUR.

Output should draw an analog clock out of asterisks showing the hour N.

---

### Notes:

•The minute hand must be longer than the hour hand (in terms of number of asterisks used)

•The minute hand must be at least 2 asterisks.

•Noon, 3pm, 6pm, and 9pm will always be orthogonal. Your output for intermediary hours, when arranged by degrees, should be in the same order as the hours of the day. What I mean is at noon the hour hand is 0º and at 3pm the hour hand is 90º so for your output cases of 1pm and 2pm the following must be true:  `0pm_deg < 1pm_deg < 2pm_deg < 3pm_deg`. Apart from this rule the actual degree amount can be whatever you decide, obviously it will change depending on font and other native factors.

•The connecting joint between the hour hand and minute hand is a circular/oval unicode character of any kind. `o, O, •, 0, etc.`

---

### Example Input / Output (May vary depending on drawing styles)

```
 N = 3;

 *
 *
 *
 O  *  *
```

---

```
 N = 4;

 *
 *
 *
 O
    *
       *
```

---

```
 N = 5;

 *
 *
 *
 0
  *
   *
```

---

```
 N = 6;

 *
 *
 o
 *
```

---

```
 N = 7;

      *
      *
      *
      •
    *
  *
```

---

```
 N = 0,12,24;

 *
 *
 *
 o
```

---

Example of Differentiating Outputs:

```
 N = 4     VS     N = 5     VS     N = 6

  *                *                *
  *                *                *
  O                O                O
      *              *              *
```

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the program with the shortest bytecount wins!

Comment: Hours usually are from 0-23 or 1-12 not 0-24 unless you have 25 hours in a day

Comment: The minute hand must be longer than the hour hand, but do they need to maintain their sizes? E.g., could the minute hand for `3` be a different size than the minute hand for `7`?

Comment: @LliwTelracs but `23:00` is `11:00`. In my mind I was trying to loop around back to the 12 hand again

Comment: @AdmBorkBork They do not need to maintain their sizes. I'll edit that in.

Comment: Do the hour-hand asterisks need to be in a straight line? Your example for N=4 doesn't have this property (maybe a typo).

Comment: @GregMartin I think that is my fault

Comment: Can you include a test case with 6 < N < 12, so we see an example where the minute hand isn't on the left side of the output?

Comment: @GregMartin Good catch, thanks! And Wheat I think I had the typo in my original haha

Comment: @LliwTelracs the 0-24 thing should be fine for this challenge since `0%12 = 12%12 = 24%12`

Comment: @LliwTelracs  Some days sure feel like they do!

Comment: @LliwTelracs Depends.  In some places, 0:00 is start-of-day and 24:00 is end-of-day, where 24:00 Monday = 0:00 Tuesday.   It's just nothing exists besides 24:00:00.0000000

Comment: Are leading or trailing blanks/newlines accepted? What about padding?

Comment: @Titus since this is a drawing challenge I'll rule that it's okay to use freedom in drawing, the only requirements are the actual asterisks and circles themselves, as for padding (whether it be from new lines or spaces) I'm okay with it!

Answer (score 18):

## Javascript (ES6), <strike>105</strike> <strike>76</strike> 65 bytes

```js
F=N=>`  *
ab*12
 9@3
87654`.replace(/\w/g,y=>'0x'+y^N%12?' ':'*')
```

```html
<!-- Snippet Demo: -->
N =  <input type="number" min="0" max="24" value="2" id="I" />
<button onclick="console.log(F(I.value))">Run</button>
```

- **-29 bytes:**

  - Reduced size of minute and hour hand to 2 and 1 asterisks respectively. Smaller clock = less bytes :-P
- **-11 bytes:**

  - Changed string comparison to numeric comparison.
  - `y==(N%12).toString(16)?'*':' '` -> `'0x'+y^N%12?' ':'*'`

### Original with longer hands: (<strike>105</strike> 94 bytes)

```js
F=N=>`    *
a b * 1 2
  ab*12
  99@33
  87654
8 7 6 5 4`.replace(/\w/g,y=>'0x'+y^N%12?' ':'*')
```

```html
<!-- Snippet Demo: -->
N =  <input type="number" min="0" max="24" value="2" id="I" />
<button onclick="console.log(F(I.value))">Run</button>
```

Comment: That's really clever!

Comment: Oh wow I like this a lot!

Comment: Oops. My Python answer looks a bit like your original. I posted before I saw your answer, honestly. Guess we had the same idea with hex.

Comment: and I somehow read it as "The hour hand must be at least 2..." so +1 for reading it properly and shortening the hands.

Comment: @ElPedro that's what I thought I read originally also :)

Answer (score 14):

### CSS/HTML(JavaScript), 62 + 106 = <s>180</s> 168 bytes

```css
pre{position:absolute;left:99px;bottom:99px;transform-origin:50% 80%}
```

```html
<input oninput=h.style.transform=`rotate(${this.value*30}deg)`><pre>*
*
o</pre><pre id=h>*

</pre>
```

Edit: Saved 9 bytes thanks to @nderscore.

Comment: Very cool idea!

Comment: Really nice answer.

Comment: You can shave 4 bytes off your input tag by swapping it with this `<body onload=f(prompt())>`

Comment: You could also embed the function code in the oninput attribute directly: `<input oninput=h.style.transform=\`rotate(${this.value*30}deg)\`>`

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>148</s> <s>140</s> 135 bytes

-8 by deleting some leftover spaces and an unneeded newline.

-5 by changing `(' ','*')` to `' *'`

```python
a=input()
b='''    *
a b * 1 2
  ab*12
9 9 o 3 3
  87654
8 7 6 5 4'''
for x in range(1,12):b=b.replace(hex(x)[2],' *'[x==a%12])
print b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#DctLCsMgFEbh@V3FPyk@CIVr3gVXEjLQYttAMSIpuHvrGX5wqrNHTL9LKvJWCIGWJgcPDYYhwHnNhlasONGjb7LM0zjQghkTRgztoteZUXBEZBffQXLHRj289fcc0tc9g/yEIovazN4JaLEVa92Nza4o5SNe8LUy/wE)

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 144 bytes

```c
#define v ,t
h;t(i){putchar(i>12?i-9:h^i?32:42);}n(i){h=i%12;puts("  *")v(10)v(11)v(h)v(1)v(2)v(19)v(12)v(9)v(57)v(3)v(19)v(8)v(7)v(6)v(5)v(4);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#NU7LDoIwELzzFRsMoUVMoOCLqvwIMUGBtAcrqasX4rfjrgmHmZ3s7GPmVdcP1vXwgRQDo1FYOY1vvJvWC3vJVW03x8pcbV2oqlRSfx1PmLONcqVp8CVCgCSUH5FnTDmRYUFQXI9MrFhs90TF0j4QuLFjh1DS@dk6hEdr6Q2JNgVOAkkCNwlTAADD0/8tPGcaT6rUS9q4cbGUoydzEGHUVY0LU5SpE7heS827vse3d5Dp4Dv/AA)

Comment: +1; Holy recursion! I find it hilarious that you can save bytes in a code-golf challenge by macroing a comma ahha

Comment: I wasn't expecting it either, though there's no recursion in sight. This is a hard coded answer, albeit slightly obfuscated.

Comment: I don't think you need the space before the comma

Answer (score 4):

## SmileBASIC, <s>90</s> <s>88</s> 74 bytes

```
INPUT H?("  *"+" "*47)*2;"  o
R=H/1.9LOCATE 2.5+SIN(R)*2,3.5-COS(R)*2?"*
```

Example output:

```
? 5
  *
  *
  o
  
   *

? 3
  *
  *
  o *
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>86</s> 85 bytes

-1 byte, better clockface (credit DuctrTape, as used in my Jelly answer)

```python
def f(h):print(*([c,' *'[h%12+64==ord(c)]][c>'@']for c in'''
K*A
J*B
I0C
HFD
G E'''))
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@5@SmqaQppGhaVVQlJlXoqGlEZ2so66gpR6doWpopG1mYmubX5SikawZGxudbKfuoB6bll@kkKyQmaeurs7lreXI5aXlxOVp4Mzl4ebC5a7gChTW1PwPUpQBVKRQlJiXnqphZKppxcUJsSFDk4szDUxC@Jr/AQ)**

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>35 34</s> 33 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ị“ tI©’Œ?Ḋ¤µ⁶ẋ13”*⁸¦Ṗ;“**o”ṙ7s5ZY
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#AUQAu///4buL4oCcIHRJwqnigJnFkj/huIrCpMK14oG24bqLMTPigJ0q4oG4wqbhuZY74oCcKipv4oCd4bmZN3M1Wln///8yMQ)** (`tI©`!) or see all **[(0 - 24)](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9wd/ejhjkKJZ6HVj5qmHl0kv3DHV2Hlhza@qhx28Nd3YbGjxrmaj1q3HFo2cOd06yBKrW08oFCD3fONC82jYr8b2T6cMe2Q1uP7jnc/qhpTSQI/wcA)**.

#### How?

```
ị“ tI©’Œ?Ḋ¤µ⁶ẋ13”*⁸¦Ṗ;“**o”ṙ7s5ZY - Main link: h
          ¤                       - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
 “ tI©’                           -     base 250 number: 522956007
       Œ?                         - shortest permutation of [1,N] that would be at
                                     that index in a lexicographically sorted
                                     list: [2,3,4,5,6,7,1,12,11,10,9,8,13]
         Ḋ                        - dequeue: [3,4,5,6,7,1,12,11,10,9,8,13]
ị                                 - index into (1-based and modular, so h=2 picks 4,
                                     as does h=14 [as do h=26, h=-10, etc.])
           µ                      - monadic chain separation (call the result j)
            ⁶                     - space character
             ẋ13                  - repeat 13 times
                   ¦              - apply to index...
                  ⁸               - ...left argument (j)
                ”*                -     an asterisk character (replacemes the space
                                         at index j with an asterisk)
                    Ṗ             - pop the last character off the list †
                     ;“**o”       - concatenate "**o"
                           ṙ7     - rotate left by 7 ‡
                             s5   - split into chunks of length 5 (columns)
                               Z  - transpose (get the rows of the clock)
                                Y - join with line feeds
                                  - implicit print
```

Note that `“ tI©’Œ?Ḋ` (permutation at index, dequeued) is a byte save over `“9ȧỤ_ÑḶ’b⁴` (base 16 of), which is a byte save over `“¦þxṙ<ȥ’ḃ13` (bijective base 13 of).

`†` Regarding the pop - we have an extra space in the string, which is where the asterisk for 0, 12, 24 will go to to allow mod-12 indexing of the list of indexes, popping the last character off there is byte-cheaper than doing the concatenation of `“**o”` beforehand and overwriting one of those asterisks.

`‡` Regarding the rotation - this is a byte save over constructing a string with the `“**o” in the middle (either with it before or after the asterisk placement).

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 148 bytes

```
c n=mapM_ putStrLn$(t(n-3)!(t n!(\_->'*')))(map(\x->(2!(\_->x))"     ")"**O  ")
n!f=(\(x,a:y)->x++f a:y).splitAt n
t n=2+truncate(2.5*sin(n*pi/6))
```

Function c is the one that solves the given task

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + Unix utilities, 57 bytes

```bash
tr `dc -e12o$1O%p` \*<<<'B*1
A*2
9O3
864
7 5'|tr 1-9AB \
```

(There's a space after the final backslash.)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@19SpJCQkqygm2polK9i6K9akKAQo2VjY6PupGXI5ahlxGXpb8xlYWbCZa5gql4DVG2oa@nopBCj8P//f2MA)

Not a very pretty clock, but it meets all the requirements.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 71 bytes

1 asterisk hours hand, 2 asterisk minutes hand.

```php
$s="  *
  *  
  O  
";$s[ord(BGHNTSRQPJDE[$argv[1]%12])&31]="*";echo$s;
```

takes input from command line argument; run with `-nr`.

1. define template
2. map hour to position (decode from letter) and set character at position to asterisk
3. print

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 41 bytes

This is too slow for TIO.

```
14Ýœ•2!&ô÷‰•èv… *@y_2L11+¹12%0‚ìyå+èJ}3ô»
```

For similar code working on TIO try [this](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#AUgAt///4oCiR8OOw6bCruKAmsW@asKx4oCiMTVCUzE1w7Z24oCmICpAeV8yTDExK8K5MTIlMOKAmsOsecOlK8OoSn0zw7TCu///MTk)

Pretty sure this can still be both golfed and sped up.
Explanation coming later.

Answer (score 1):

### [Logicode](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Logicode) 634 bytes

Couldn't figure out how to input so there is a var a=... for the input at the top of tio link

```
circ v(a)->cond((a&1000)+0)&a->0/a
circ n(a)->cond a&10000->((a&100)+0)|!(a&100)&((a&011)|100)/a
circ y(a)->cond((a&100)+0)&a->a&10011/a
var s=@100000
var m=@101010
var x=y(n(v(a)))
var e=x&1000
var f=(x&100)+0
var t=(x&10)+00
var o=(x&1)+000
circ r(a,b)->cond(a)->b/@a
out s+s+s+s+m
out r(e&t&!o,m)+s+r(o&e&t,m)+s+m+s+r(o&!e&!f&!t,m)+s+r(t&!o&!f&!e,m)
out s+s+r(e&t&!o,m)+r(e&t&o,m)+m+r(o&!t&!f&!e,m)+r(t&!o&!f&!e,m)
out r(e&o&!t,m)+s+r(e&o&!t,m)+s+@110000+s+r(t&o&!f&!e,m)+s+r(t&o&!f&!e,m)
out s+s+r(e&!t&!o,m)+r((f&t&o),m)+r(f&t&!o,m)+r(f&!t&o,m)+r(f&!t&!o,m)
out r(e&!t&!o,m)+s+r(f&t&o,m)+s+r(f&t&!o,m)+s+r(f&o&!t,m)+s+r(f&!t&!o,m)
```

Have given up on golfing this. Could make it shorter at the cost of making the clock look horrible though.

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/nexus/logicode#bZFNboMwEIX3OYWtStZYSRtTZUvFDXoGQ0FCLXZkHApS7k49Y34cpfJmvsebmWczaMd0nmVKKXZ4ac315llrWNka7aY39ml@JvZr3XfPblfmLXu/zFXrKjaAlq8flTVfAKAF9sujkgJVddYHMpndFC0q4GJH950vtSAxk3eEtXt6WrFtIMqy4BxC/j4vaLgi6pDwEI35BAYwrZQk1PlIUQiaHMZlMLGPHDCyJUZUMZMDfSq3O4WiPBf6YMOj9cd4OiIHtfCC21Mng@bAisARukXgteCN4H61oJ2UOijbyHRQrKns4gi/Nfw7ABtssiKlgv65WlbvjU/CQxS@Z4EGw8gITRISLyXSmj5sgXj6Ls16of5hSKQ0@j5onv8A)